# QToolTip with animated gif

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have the following question. I use qt for GUI. And I need tooltips with animated gif. Is it possible to show tooltip with animated gif ? I've managed to create tooltip with png or jpeg, but no gif..

Comment: Do you have a custom `QToolTip`? You need to set a movie to a `QLabel` http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qmovie.html#details

Comment: @headsvk, can you show some example of custom QToolTip?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```
widget->setToolTip("Hello <img src=\"image.gif\" />");
```

But the GIF will not be animated. If you really want the animation, you need to use (like as said headsvk) `QMovie` and create a custom `QToolTip`.